# best approach for debugging in PHP and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, debugging, error-handling, die

Currently my codes look like this:

```
Query 1 or die(debug(mysql->error));
Query 2 or die(debug(mysql->error));
Query 3 or die(debug(mysql->error));
Query 4 or die(debug(mysql->error));
Query 5 or die(debug(mysql->error));

function debug(x)
{
  echo 'The error is' x;
}
```

The benifit is at any time if I want to remove debug messages in my website I just comment 1  line in debug function.

My questions are

1. Is it good to use die? if die get called at Query 3, do the Query 4,Query 5 will get executed?
2. Is that the best approach?

Comment: Yes this is a good approach ..

Comment: "if die get called at Query 3, do the Query 4,Query 5 will get executed?" No.

Comment: This is a bad approach for a production system. Using `die()` in a production application will terminate the application with, at best, a cryptic message to the user. You should handle the error. Recover if you can, but at least find a way to notify yourself there's been an error, and display a friendly message.

Comment: Are you using Prepared SQL Statements? As far as debugging is concerned, the ErrorCode that the DB returns to PHP is quite broad and at most times not intuitive. For a development system I would recommend echo-ing the SQL.

Comment: @MikeW what if i want the script not to stop?

Comment: @ZainShah120 die() makes the script stop. If you want the script not to stop then die() is a very bad approach. In fact, die() is just a very bad approach. Every database model/engine provides feedback on query errors which can be inspected and dealt with. Die should really probably die.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1-Is it good to use die? if die get called at Query 3, do the Query
>   4,Query 5 will get executed?

No. die() means the script would stop. Simply stop and deliver the error.

> 2-Is that the best approach?

Yes. It's an approach I love to use.

However it's all well only in the **development** stages, and it ruins user experience by breaking the page and even giving mysql errors.

If your site is live, better learn how to use error handling and give your users an error they'd understand. [Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_error_handling.htm) is a nice tutorial.

Read [die()](http://www.php.net/die).

Comment: what if want it not to stop?

Comment: @ZainShah120 Then don't use die() and echo the mysql_error().

Comment: Yes. `Query 5 or echo(mysql->error);` or `debug(mysql->error);` @ZainShah120